# Reshaping Data in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that currently looks like the following:

```
X  |  A  |  B  |  C  
X1 |  1  |  3  |  5
X2 |  3  |  5  |  7
```

I want to reshape it either in Pandas or OpenRefine so it looks like the following:

```
A  | X1 | 1
A  | X2 | 3
B  | X1 | 3
B  | X2 | 5
C  | X1 | 5
C  | X2 | 7
```

I know I have done something like it in the past, but cannot for the life of me remember how.

Comment: This question smells like a duplicate... can someone find the right one?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ mark it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `df.melt()`

```
df.melt(id_vars='X', value_vars=['A','B','C'])


    X   variable    value
0   X1  A           1
1   X2  A           3
2   X1  B           3
3   X2  B           5
4   X1  C           5
5   X2  C           7
```

Comment: @Wen Nice gold badge Pandas badge there.  Congrats.

Comment: @ScottBoston just get it today ... I even do not notice that :-)